# Ubuntu 20.04.2....Bonded NICs as TRUNK interface...assign IP from a specific VLAN to the bonded NICs?

Tags: netplan, network-bonding, ip-address, vlan

I am attempting to setup BONDED NICs (2x 10G). We have 6 total NICs, 4x 1G and 2x 10G, do not plan to use the 1G connections at this time.

Looks like I have the NICs bonded (no errors in networkctl command and the 2 switches (Cisco Nexus) show both ports operational, not suspended).

I have KVM installed, and I spun up a VM to test for VLAN functionality on the BONDED interface and it appears to work (I need to spin up a couple to test for different VLANs).

However, what I can't seem to figure out, is how to assign a static IP to the BONDED interface, so we can SSH to that IP for management. At this time I have to assign an IP to one of the 1G NICs to be able to SSH to it.

10.100.60.x = VLAN760 FYI....

What am I missing? Please help.

Thanks
Dirk

EDIT: updated config and networkctl results:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      optional: true
      addresses:
      - 10.100.60.21/24
      gateway4: 10.100.60.120
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.160.100
        search:
        - aperia.local
        - ddsos.ofc
#    eno2:
#      dhcp4: no
#      dhcp6: no
#      optional: true
#    eno3:
#      dhcp4: no
#      dhcp6: no
#      optional: true
#    eno4:
#      dhcp4: no
#      dhcp6: no
#      optional: true
    ens5f0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    ens5f1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ens5f0, ens5f1]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer3+4
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        min-links: 1
  vlans:
    vlan701:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 701
      link: bond0
    vlan702:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 702
      link: bond0
    vlan703:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 703
      link: bond0
    vlan704:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 704
      link: bond0
    vlan705:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 705
      link: bond0
    vlan711:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 711
      link: bond0
    vlan712:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 712
      link: bond0
    vlan713:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 713
      link: bond0
    vlan714:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 714
      link: bond0
    vlan715:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 715
      link: bond0
    vlan721:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 721
      link: bond0
    vlan722:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 722
      link: bond0
    vlan723:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 723
      link: bond0
    vlan724:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 724
      link: bond0
    vlan725:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 725
      link: bond0
    vlan760:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 760
      link: bond0
    vlan100:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 100
      link: bond0
    vlan101:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 101
      link: bond0
    vlan111:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 111
      link: bond0
    vlan115:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 115
      link: bond0
    vlan210:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 210
      link: bond0
    vlan125:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 125
      link: bond0
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bond0]
#      parameters:
#           stp: true
#           forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br100:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan100 ]
    br101:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan101 ]
    br111:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan111 ]
    br115:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan115 ]
    br125:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan125 ]
    br210:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan210 ]
    br701:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan701 ]
    br702:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan702 ]
    br703:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan703 ]
    br704:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan704 ]
    br705:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan705 ]
    br711:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan711 ]
    br712:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan712 ]
    br713:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan713 ]
    br714:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan714 ]
    br715:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan715 ]
    br721:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan721 ]
    br722:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan722 ]
    br723:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan723 ]
    br724:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan724 ]
    br725:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan725 ]
    br760:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan760 ]
```

```
IDX LINK       TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo         loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eno1       ether    routable    configured
  3 eno2       ether    off         unmanaged
  4 eno3       ether    off         unmanaged
  5 ens5f0     ether    enslaved    configured
  6 eno4       ether    off         unmanaged
  7 ens5f1     ether    enslaved    configured
  8 virbr0     bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged
  9 virbr0-nic ether    off         unmanaged
 10 bond0      bond     enslaved    configured
 11 br0        bridge   degraded    configured
 12 br100      bridge   degraded    configured
 13 br101      bridge   degraded    configured
 14 br111      bridge   degraded    configured
 15 br115      bridge   degraded    configured
 16 br125      bridge   degraded    configured
 17 br210      bridge   degraded    configured
 18 br701      bridge   degraded    configured
 19 br702      bridge   degraded    configured
 20 br703      bridge   degraded    configured
 21 br704      bridge   degraded    configured
 22 br705      bridge   degraded    configured
 23 br711      bridge   degraded    configured
 24 br712      bridge   degraded    configured
 25 br713      bridge   degraded    configured
 26 br714      bridge   degraded    configured
 27 br715      bridge   degraded    configured
 28 br721      bridge   degraded    configured
 29 br722      bridge   degraded    configured
 30 br723      bridge   degraded    configured
 31 br724      bridge   degraded    configured
 32 br725      bridge   degraded    configured
 33 br760      bridge   degraded    configured
 34 vlan713    vlan     enslaved    configured
 35 vlan725    vlan     enslaved    configured
 36 vlan100    vlan     enslaved    configured
 37 vlan701    vlan     enslaved    configured
 38 vlan705    vlan     enslaved    configured
 39 vlan723    vlan     enslaved    configured
 40 vlan712    vlan     enslaved    configured
 41 vlan714    vlan     enslaved    configured
 42 vlan721    vlan     enslaved    configured
 43 vlan704    vlan     enslaved    configured
 44 vlan724    vlan     enslaved    configured
 45 vlan722    vlan     enslaved    configured
 46 vlan711    vlan     enslaved    configured
 47 vlan702    vlan     enslaved    configured
 48 vlan101    vlan     enslaved    configured
 49 vlan715    vlan     enslaved    configured
 50 vlan703    vlan     enslaved    configured
 51 vlan210    vlan     enslaved    configured
 52 vlan760    vlan     enslaved    configured
 53 vlan111    vlan     enslaved    configured
 54 vlan125    vlan     enslaved    configured
 55 vlan115    vlan     enslaved    configured

55 links listed.
```

Comment: Looking at one of our bonded NICs, the only thing that is not present in your bond0 block is the "dhcp4: false" setting. Maybe just missing that?

Comment: Just tried that, no joy.